# Reserved word on eloquent models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Product model and a Attribute model.

Products have Attributes.

Problem is I cant use Attributes as a member of a Product class that extends eloquent as eloquent uses this already. Is there a way around this?

```
class Product extends Model 
{
    protected $attributes;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Well you can call it something different. e.g. `productAttributes`

Comment: but that just sucks... :-)

Comment: I know. but I don't think there's a good alternative. The Laravel source uses the `attributes` hardcoded so you can't just override a function or change a config. You'd have to override a LOT of code. That's not worth it. Maybe it would be an option to rename your model?

Comment: Already have options, variants and attributes

Comment: `property/properties` maybe?

Comment: think i will go with productAttributes but that is definatly an option

Comment: Okay. I posted an "official" answer so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get around renaming your relation. e.g. `productAttributes`.

The problem here is, that the `attributes` property is used a lot by Eloquent and there is no way to change that by configuration or overriding a small piece of code. You would need to override a lot of classes to change the name to something else, which is definitely not worth it.